# Lazarus TListView not showing correct column header color

Tags: listview, lazarus

> `Windows 10
>
>   Lazarus IDE v.1.4.0`

If I drop a TListView on a new application and set it's viewstyle property = vsReport, and then add columns. the Column header color is the same as the rest of the control, instead of the usual clButtonFace color I am use to.

Is this a Windows 10 thing?

[image]

Comment: Look at the header of Windows Explorer when you have it in detail view. It's normal that the header is the same color as the rest. It's part of the new theme in Windows 10.